# How do you use the /execute command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

how do you use the `/execute` command? it seems dumb.  I tried to use it for something, but the commands work exactly the same

Answer (score 1):

The execute command is used to call a command on a specific entity.

From [Gamepedia](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#execute):

> Syntax:
>
> ```
> execute <entity> <x> <y> <z> <command …>
> ```

An example would be if you wanted to strike all zombies with lightning you could use:

```
execute @e[type=Zombie] ~ ~ ~ summon LightningBolt
```

So as you can see you can use it to spawn things near entities.

Good luck!